# How to pass dynamic argument in vuejs custom directive

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <img v-directive:dynamic_literal />
    </div>
</template>
```

E.g. dynamic_literal = 'ok'
such that in custom directive:

```
Vue.directive('directive', {
    bind(el, binding) {  binding.arg  // should return 'ok'
```

How can I use dynamic_literal as a variable or a constant whose value should be assigned under data or prop.

I tried with v-directive:{{dynamic_literal}} and :v-directive="dynamic_literal" but no use.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Vue 2.6 seems to have this feature, but I am unable to get it to work. Please see: https://medium.com/the-vue-point/vue-2-6-released-66aa6c8e785e

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little late but maybe it's of some use... You can actually get dynamic arguments in Vue directives by using the `vnode` parameter passed to the directive hook functions. We'll use the argument itself as the property name that we want to access in the context of `vnode`. This also works with computed properties, for example.

```
Vue.directive('directive', function(el, binding, vnode){
    el.innerHTML = vnode.context[binding.arg];
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: '<div v-directive:argument></div>',
    data: {
        argument: 0
    },
    mounted() {
        setInterval(() => ++this.argument, 1000);
    }
});
```

(using the [function shorthand](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Function-Shorthand) for directives here)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hmrhejy2/)

Comment: This is the only way I could make computed properties "compute" as an argument for a custom directive… cheers.

Answer (score 6):

working for me:

```
<div v-mydirective:[dynamicArg]="foo">
```

to access it with `binding.arg`

more info: https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0003-dynamic-directive-arguments.md

Comment: Works for me and simple

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any way you could make the *argument* dynamic, but the value can be.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.directive("test", {
  bind(el, binding){
    console.log(binding)
  },
  update(el, binding){
    console.log(binding)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    dynamic_literal: 'ok'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1 v-test="dynamic_literal">Hello World</h1>
  <button @click="dynamic_literal='not ok!'">Change literal</button>
</div>
```

Note when you run the above snippet that the `value` property changes in the log when you click the button.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to pass dynamic arguments to a directive but you can create an intermediate component that dynamically render that value passed via prop.

```
export default {
  render(createElement) {
    return createElement(
      'img', {
        directives: [
          {
            name: 'directive',
            arg: this.literal,
          },
        ],
      }
    );
  },
  props: {
    literal: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
};
```

So this code should do the trick

```
<template>
    <div>
        <new-img-component :literal="dynamic_literal" />
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you can try to do something like this:

```
<div v-mydirective="{text: dynamic_literal}">
```

with `dynamic_literal` is a variable in your props/data of the component

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue, where my binding.value was meant to be dynamic, but it wouldn't update or act reactively.
The resolution for me was adding `beforeUpdate` when creating the directive. Initially, I only used `mounted`, so the first value provided always persisted.